# How can I set up SSH tunneling to access a webserver behind a firewall?

Tags: ssh, webserver, remote-debugging, putty, tunneling

How would I access a webserver behind a firewall? I'm developing an application for this webserver which is not yet open to the public.

Someone walked me through this before, so I know it can be done. However, it has been about four months and I haven't been able to do it again.

I'm using Putty to connect to the remote machine. From that machine I can open the site http://dev.server.address:83 using Firefox. However, I want to be able to open http://localhost:80 on my machine to see the same page.

I'm using the server address and port 83 for the "source port"
I'm using localhost:80 for the "destination port"

Comment: this question should be moved to serverfault.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enter "80" into *Source port* and `dev.server.address:83` to *Destination*.

[And don't forget to click the "Add" button before you leave the configuration screen. If you don't click that, PuTTY doesn't actually create a tunnel. I fell for that gotcha quite a few times myself]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using 127.0.0.1:80 instead of localhost:80? I don't use PuTTY, but when I use SSH on my machine, I have to specify 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought that 127.0.0.1 and localhost were always equivalent (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), so I wonder whey it wouldn't work sometimes.

Comment: I thought that too, believe me. I have no explanation as for why it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a webserver running on your local machine? If that is listening on port 80 `http://localhost:80` wont work. Alternatively try mapping the source to a different port (12345 for eg.) and then try `http://localhost:12345` in your browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This wasn't the problem in this case, but it is something that I will keep in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can also make it happen with:

```
$ ssh -f -R 83:localhost:80 user@dev.server.address
```

Provided that you have an SSH account named "user".